# Opening a new tab/window after an AJAX call

Tags: javascript, ajax

I need help making an ajax call and using the response to open a new tab; the code I have sort of works but if the function is called more than once, it will simply replace the contents of the first tab instead of opening another one.

```
function openInNewTab(url){
    let newTab = window.open("about:blank", "new_tab")
    $.ajax('api/path').done(function(response){
        newTab.location = url + '&data='+response;      
    })
}
```

How can I make it so a new tab will be opened each time the function is called?

Answer (score 1):

Try this (url should be full qualified url, e.g. `http://www.example.com/path/to/your/file/and/so/on`)

```
function openInNewTab(url){
    $.ajax('api/path').done(function(response){
        window.open( url + '&data='+response, "_blank");    
    })
}
```

Comment: I tried this but the browser seems to be treating it as a pop-up so I am trying to avoid that

Comment: That's expected. Every time when the ajax call is done, the window will open a new tab, with current page which send the ajax call remains untouched. Please let me know if I miss anything.